# Is asking for leaked data on topic here?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119606/where-can-i-find-a-copy-of-the-panama-papers-leak/119608#119608
.
I haven't seen this question asked on any of the stack exchanges. What is the general acceptability of asking for leak documents on security.se and the rest of stack exchange?

Is it a bad idea to ask these questions on one's public profile?

Comment: Just FYI, I'd be a little stealthier about trying to get your hands on incriminating evidence and extremely personal details regarding the secret lives of rich and powerful people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a question would be on topic at [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) site. In fact, it was already asked there, and well received: [Downloading the Panama Papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7460).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think asking for leaked document is in the spirit of this site.

We are a Q&A site, aiming to help people solve security problem. We're not here to spread data, especially personal data, nor be an awareness website. Other sites have this kind of topic the their main goal. I think of wikileaks for example.

Helping accessing publicly document is not a real security problem, and not really ethical to do coming from security professionals.

Answer (score 3):

The question you posted does not ask for leaked data.

Your question asks where you can find a copy of the data.

That is not even vaguely a security question as per the scope of this site. It doesn't matter what you put after "Where can I find..." in most cases.

It's a question you should ask of Google or other search engine.